# Recursive Palindrome method debugging

Tags: java, debugging

I am attempting to write a method that tests to see if a string is a palindrome. This is what I have so far:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
    boolean flag = false;

    if (word.length() < 2) {
        flag = true;
    } else if (word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length() - 1)) {
        flag = isPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length() - 2));
    }

    return flag;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is, this method consistently returns true for strings of the form `"aaaba"`, where the pair that should cause false to be propagated back through the stack is in the middle of the string. I'm banging my head against the wall trying to see where my error is, but to no avail. Perhaps a fresh set of eyes will see something I'm missing?

Comment: Try using some print statements to see which characters are being compared each time. This should help you narrow down the problem area.

Comment: All of that as opposed to `return word.equals(new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString());`?

Comment: @JoshM It is a useful recursion exercise...

Comment: Fair enough, I was unaware of the requirements and was just suggesting that there are alternate ways of doing it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your recursive call, you should subtract 1 from the length of the string, not 2:

```
// start index inclusive, end index exclusive
flag = isPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length() - 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Yeah, I should have noticed that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Change the `endIndex` in the `substring(startIndex, endIndex)` method. Note that according to Java Docs:

> **public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)**
>   Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.

Change it to:

```
word.substring(1, word.length() - 1)
```

so, let's say `word = "aaba"`, this method will return `"ab"`.

---

Also, you can simplify your code by getting rid of `flag` and returning the result directly:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word)
{
    if (word.length() < 2) {
        return true;
    } else if (word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length() - 1)) {
        return isPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length() - 1));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it was something simple that I would end up kicking myself for not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
 if(word.length() == 0 || word.length() == 1)
     return true; // If length is 0 or 1 then it is palindrome

 if(word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length()-1))
     return isPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length()-1));
     //Check the first and last char of the string if they are same
     //then continue the same for a substring by removing the first
     //and last character. And continue this until the string completes

 return false; //I fthe case doesn't match

}
```

Comment: It was the index I was using that was the issue. Thank you!